# content of ContentControl in a WPF library UserControl is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a UserControl BaseDrawingControl which contains ZoomAndPanControl which is derived from ContentControl, IScrollInfo. The control is in WPF User control library.

The issue is that in the designer the ZoomAndPanControl always reports 'Object Reference not set to an instance of an object' and using the library control in a test app generates an null exception on the content property.

**EDIT**
the null exception occurs when the ArrangeOverride method of the ZoomAndPanControl is called and content.DesiredSize is referenced.

I have tried creating the UserControl directly in the test app and the designer and the runtime work ie content is valid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShapeObjectDrawing.BaseDrawingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:shapeObjectDrawing="clr-namespace:ShapeObjectDrawing"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="600">


    <!--
        Wrap the ZoomAndPanControl in a ScrollViewer.
        When the scaled content that is displayed in ZoomAndPanControl is larger than the viewport onto the content
        ScrollViewer's scrollbars can be used to manipulate the offset of the viewport.    
        -->
    <ScrollViewer
            x:Name="Scroller"
            CanContentScroll="True"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            >

        <!--
            This is the control that handles zooming and panning.
            -->
        <shapeObjectDrawing:ZoomAndPanControl
                x:Name="ZoomAndPanControl"
                Background="LightGray"
                >

            <!-- 
                This is the content that is displayed.
                -->
            <Grid
                    x:Name="theGrid"
                    Width="2000"
                    Height="2000"
                    >
                <!--
                    This Canvas is the main part of the content that is displayed.
                    -->
                <Canvas
                        x:Name="contentCanvas"
                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=CanvasBackground, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        >
                </Canvas>

                <!--
                    This Canvas and Border are used as a very simple way to render a drag rectangle that the user
                    uses to specify an area to zoom in on.
                    -->
                <Canvas
                        x:Name="dragZoomCanvas"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        >
                    <Border 
                            x:Name="dragZoomBorder"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="Silver"
                            CornerRadius="1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            />
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </shapeObjectDrawing:ZoomAndPanControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried using your `user control` in xaml as a static resource with `x:Key`?

Comment: _"test app generates an null exception on the content property"_ what does it mean? Show where exception occurs in debugger.

Comment: I have added an EDIT to shown where the exception occurs. The content property of the ZoomAndPanControl ( ContentControl ) is null